# Is there any boto3 function for Tagging CodeBuild Projects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Is there any boto3 function for tagging CodeBuild Projects?

trying to add tags to CodeBuild projects using boto3. Tried using tag_resources() that is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

From the AWS docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/tags-add.html

This is for existing resources. There's an example for new resources as well.

```
import boto3
personalize = boto3.client('personalize')

add_tags_response = personalize tag_resource(
  resourceArn = "resourceArn",
  tags = [
    {
      'tagKey': 'Environment',
      'tagValue': 'Test'
    },
    {
      'tagKey': 'Owner',
      'tagValue': 'xyzCorp'    
    }
  ]    
)
```

Comment: Looks like your example is missing a dot between `personalize` and `tag_resource`

Comment: It is throwing this error when "errorMessage": "'Personalize' object has no attribute 'tag_resource'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",